# Youtube Real-time video playing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, youtube-api

I'am new here and with problems. I want to create website, where people come in, and see the same video at the same time from youtube. Its like video streaming, but the video is uploaded older. Is this possible? Any suggestion is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: everybody come here for problems and solving them :P

Comment: I think the most common solution is to embed a YouTube video player within the web page. Is this what you are trying to do?

Comment: It's sort of possible, but it wouldn't be very precise (maybe a second or 2 out of synch).  It would take a lot of work to do this though, and it may all be for no good reason.

Comment: Yes, i want to embed video to my webpage. Just playing youtube playlist in site. People come in, and see the video from elapsed time, ex. 00.12sec. just streaming video. sorry for bad english

Answer (score 0):

I think the [`player.seekTo()`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Playback_controls) function is what you're looking for.

If the start time is `numberOfSeconds`, try `player.seekTo(numberOfSeconds, true)` to skip ahead to that time.

Comment: Note that this information is from the [YouTube Player API for iframe Embeds](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference), which replaces the older (and now [deprecated](http://youtube-eng.blogspot.com/2015/01/youtube-now-defaults-to-html5_27.html)) [YouTube JavaScript Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Requirements).